# Why is this slider script breaking when minified and combined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

Time to Minify my js and i have run into some scripts that just dont want to:

First we have owl-slider. I have several sliders and some other random JS and was hoping i could combine it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sliderId").owlCarousel({
   autoPlay:true,
   navigation : false,
   slideSpeed : 200,
   paginationSpeed : 400,
   items: 3,
   loop:true,
   itemsTablet: true,
   itemsMobile : true
  });
});
```

Second a old script use to display random text:

```
 $(document).ready(function change() {
    "use strict";
     var messages = [
                "text 1",
                "text 2",
                     ], i = 0;
var msg = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)];
$('#comments').html(msg).fadeIn(600).delay(10000).fadeOut(600, change);
      })();
```

How could i possibly combine these two into one js file to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minifier is in some cases very strict. So you have a litte comma mistake in your Javascript file:

```
 $(document).ready(function change() {
    "use strict";
     var messages = [
       "text 1",
       "text 2" // Here you have to delete the comma
     ], i = 0;
     var msg = messages[Math.floor(Math.random()*messages.length)];
     $('#comments').html(msg).fadeIn(600).delay(10000).fadeOut(600, change);
 })();
```

Solve this, maybe your favorite minifier and combiner works ;)